# ECharts - how to work with user-defined toolbox features?

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

(ECharts 3.5.3)

Hello all! I have added user-defined icons on ToolBox and i need to control 
them - clicking on my own icon must make it active and clear active state of other icons (data zoom e.g.) and vice versa.

I've found `setIconStatus` function, it makes my icon active, but I dont know how to call it outside of onclick event of my icon and it doesn't refresh toolbox on screen. I can call

```
api.dispatchAction({ type: 'takeGlobalCursor', key: 'myLines', brushOption: null });
```

after that, it clears zoom mode and refreshes toolbox, but I dont know how to do the same with activating of zoom mode.

Does anybody have a working example of custom toolbox with own state?